# Wpf RichTextBox copy text with textstyle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox

is there any possibility to get the rtb text as an identically copy? Included textstyle, color, or withespaces? I wrote a texteditor, and I need the text to copy into another window.

Answer (score 0):

Not simply copy, but saved.
At the first you need to take TextSelection (property [Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.documents.textselection(v=vs.110).aspx) of RichTextBox and then save it with [Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms598701(v=vs.110).aspx) method.
It can be saved in RTF format too.

```
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
    rtb.Selection.Save(mem, DataFormats.Rtf);
```